# Is it bad practice to use a Visual Studio Project folder as a virtual directory in IIS?

Tags: visual-studio, iis, virtual-directory

Is it bad practice to use a Visual Studio Project folder as a virtual directory in IIS when doing development?

Instead, should I copy the files to a separate folder once the application is compiled?

Comment: What makes you think it would be bad practice? Are you having a specific problem with that approach?

Comment: File permissions for one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you're not using this same environment to push live changes, it's fine for a development setup.  Of course if you're on a live website, it's not a good idea at all.  I think it's actually a pretty good idea for dev testing, as it saves you the step of having to move the files over to test.

Answer (score 1):

For development? No, I'm using it this way all the time.

I cannot even imagine any reason for this being bad practice.